# Any non-rails ruby forum application out there?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, forum, redis

I have a rather complete application based on sinatra. I feel in need for an easy to integrate forum module (code, extension, etc.). Running a parallel Rails application is not an option on my tiny VPS plan (I even use redis to keep a small footprint). A sinatra based forum would be great news. Thanks

Comment: you can use anything in Sinatra that uses Rack, so look for something that is Rack compatible and that may fit.

Comment: I've managed to run a rails application server in under 64 megs of ram. So this might be possible for you.

Answer (score 2):

> look for something that is Rack
>   compatible

I liked lain's suggestion and started looking for a Rack based forum. Otherwise, I might use tinyfora https://github.com/craigp/tinyfora

> A minimalist experiment in writing a
>   small, fast forum app, really just to
>   get to grips with Sinatra, DataMapper,
>   Haml and Sass.

Comment: Did you manage to get tinyfora running with Ruby 1.9.3 and data_mapper 1.2.0? I keep getting "undefined method auto_migrate! for DataMapper:Module (NoMethodError)".

Answer (score 1):

what about a hosted solution such as http://www.vanillaforums.com/ or .org for the opensource host it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> easy to integrate forum module (code, extension, etc.)

Maybe you just can create the forum inside your application itself.
Integrating different applications often takes more time and effort than creating a new, simple one.

With tools like Ruby, Sinatra/Rails you can be done with integrated forum in days (if not hours).